# How to get a link to a user's photo using telethon

Tags: python-3.x, api, telegram, telethon

I am new to working with api . I try get user photo using method GetUserPhotosRequest

```
def get_data(user):
    with TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash) as client:
        result = client(functions.photos.GetUserPhotosRequest(
            user_id=user,
            offset=0,
            max_id=0,
            limit=0
        ))
        client.flood_sleep_threshold = 24 * 60 * 60 
        array_of_photos = result.photos
        for photo in array_of_photos:
            file_reference = photo.file_reference
            file_id = photo.id
            access_hash = photo.access_hash
            path = client.download_media(access_hash)
            return path
```

But my function return None. Please help me figure it out

Comment: There is no such thing as "link to photo". What do you actually want to do? Download a user's profile picture? The question isn't very clear.

Comment: I want from file_reherence, which is a byte string view, to get a real link to the photo

Comment: As I said "link to the photo" simply does not exist. Telegram does not have links to photos. To download a photo you need the ID, hash and file reference (bot API puts all of this data in a "file id").

Comment: @Lonami Do you mind to share which method can be used to download photo? I have searched for few hours but still could not find the which method to use. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code should be `client.download_media(photo)`, not `access_hash`; see also https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.chats.ChatMethods.iter_profile_photos which has examples to download the photo.